# How to create a subdomain on the fly with ASP.Net for a Windows 2008 Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, subdomain

How can I let web users create a subdomain on the fly for Windows Server 2008 for my website?
My application is in MVC 1.0 and ASP.Net 3.5 with C#.

Comment: I think you're asking how you would change http://www.mysite.com to http://myuser.mysite.com programatically using MVC.  Am I right?

Comment: Yes BPerreault, I want to let my users create myuser.mysite.com while they are on mysite.com for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this... http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The most common way (in terms of theory) is to map *.domain.ext to your one web-application. It itself parses the request to see which subdomain is being used and therefore which "site" to show.

In practice, I'm not sure how simple this is with IIS or ASP.NET. When I still used  ASP.NET, I used [UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewrite](http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html). It was light-years ahead of the competition two years ago, and it still looks a pretty handy thing to have in a fight now.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to map wildcard you do that in IIS (and in the DNS), then you can parse the requested url to get the subdomain. Otherwise Clarify the question.